# Display Billing Company in Sales Order Grid

Tags: magento-1.9, grid, order-grid

I'm trying to add Billing Company and Shipping Company to the Sales Order Grid (Magento CE 1.9.0.1) but everything I have tried appears to have no effect - I don't even see the new column with empty data and there's nothing in the log to suggest what's wrong either. Wondered if someone might be able to help?

I'm duplicating this file:
/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/order/Grid.php as /app/code/local/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/order/Grid.php and then modifying as follows;

(_prepareCollection and _prepareColumns stripped back to simply show the new code)

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

    //New line
    $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order_address', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order_address.parent_id' ,array('company'=> 'company' ));
    $collection->addFieldToFilter('sales_flat_order_address.address_type', array('eq' => 'billing'));

    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}

protected function _prepareColumns()
{

    [...]

    $this->addColumn('company', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Billing Company'),
        'index' => 'company',
    ));

    [...]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
            {
                $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

                 $collection->getSelect()->join(array('billing'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=billing.parent_id and billing.address_type="billing"',array('*'));

                $collection->getSelect()->join(array('shipping'=>'sales_flat_order_address'),'main_table.entity_id=shipping.parent_id and shipping.address_type="shipping"',array('shipping.company as  shipping_company'));

                $this->setCollection($collection);

                 parent::_prepareCollection();
       return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
            }
```

And  add columns  in  _prepareColumns()

```
  $this->addColumn('company', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Billing company'),
                'index' => 'company',
                'filter_index' => 'billing.company',
            ));
             $this->addColumn('shipping_company', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__(' Shipping company'),
                'index' => 'shipping_company',
                'filter_index' => 'shipping_company',
            ));
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that this doesn't work either for me. :/

Comment: did you used any extension

Comment: Make sure you are editing correct file bcz it's working code

Comment: I believe it is the correct file. I have also tried it on one other Magento site and I can't get it to work there either. :/ I also have caching disabled so the update should be visible right away. I have also disabled some modules that were using Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid.

Comment: I now have the columns appearing and data pulled in. However, if I try to search in the shipping company it throws an error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'shipping_company' in 'where clause'

Comment: same here did you found a solution